# How to remove auto generated ads on Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

My Wordpress is generating Ads for first time visitor automatically. I am not able to replicate it but visitors are raising this issue.

How can I replicate first-time visitor scenario in browser? I cleared history still didn't get these ads.

Also, Suppose if ads are coming up, then how can I remove these ads from my WordPress site? Many people gave enabling/disabling plugin to check plugin which is generating these ads. Is there any other way?

Comment: Hi Bhaskar, it's possible that your site has been infected with some form of malware, possibly by a plugin or a template. Try installing Wordfence and performing a scan. It's also possible that your visitors have malware on their PC which is something you cannot control.

Answer (score 0):

To view the site as a first time user log out of the admin and clear all cookies in the browser. When you use chrome you find the settings under the application tab (see attached image) [image]